# JavaFX 8: how to add a timedelay to a listener?

Tags: javafx, listener, delay, timedelay, livesearch

I'm working on an JavaFX 8 app right now, where i have a tableView and some textFields above which make it possible to search/filter for certain columns in the tableView. I have added a listener to the textFields, to trigger the filtering automatically when a change is detected. I used the code below to do this.

```
textField_filterAddress.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            doSomething(); // in this case, filter table data and refresh tableView afterwards
        });
```

My question now is:
what's the easiest way to integrate some kind of time delay, before the filtering gets triggered? I'd like to wait a few milliseconds, because everytime the user is filtering it's executing a new database query and i don't think this is necessary for every single char that the user puts in. I'd rather wait until he/she finished his input.
Is there some kind of feature like this already built into the whole listener thing? Or do i have to implement my own solution? If so, how? I thought about some kind of concurrency solution, **so the rest of the software won't freeze during the waiting period**. But i thought i'd ask here if there is an easier solution before thinking too much about my own way...

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: How much data in total are you expecting? If it's not too much it may be reasonable to load everything initially and use a `FilteredList`.

Comment: sillyfly, unfortunatelly i wasn't allowed to load everything initially, because it was a university project with certain restrictions

Answer (score 19):

The code below will schedule to do something after a 1 second delay from the last time a text field changes.  If the text field changes within that 1 second window, the previous change is ignored and the something is scheduled to be done with the new value 1 second from the most recent change.

```
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
textField.textProperty().addListener(
    (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        pause.setOnFinished(event -> doSomething(newValue));
        pause.playFromStart();
    }
);
```

I didn't test this, but it should work :-)

A more sophisticated solution might be to make use of a "forgetful" [ReactFX suspendable event stream](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX).  ReactFX based solutions are discussed in the related question:

- [Wait before Reacting to a Property Change JavaFX 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263008/wait-before-reacting-to-a-property-change-javafx-8)

Comment: hi jewelsea, my reply is also time delayed :D
i ended up using your solution, if worked perfectly, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

The PauseTransition solution can be made more generic.

```
public abstract class DelayedListener<T> implements ChangeListener<T> {
    private final PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(1));
    private T ov, nv;

    public DelayedListener() {
        pause.setOnFinished(event -> {
            if (!Objects.equals(nv, ov)) {
                onChanged(nv);
                ov = nv;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(@NotNull ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue) {
        nv = newValue;
        pause.playFromStart();
    }

    public abstract void onChanged(T value);
}
```

Then use it with any property like this (I usually need only newValue):

```
textField.textProperty().addListener(new DelayedListener<>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String value) {
            System.out.println("Changed to " + value);
        }
    });
```