# How to change UI from other threads

Tags: java, javafx

I want to change UI in other threads and tried this way-

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                 lblToast.setText(6+"");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName())
                                                  .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
 });
```

But this code do not work.

Comment: Make it more specific, what is not working??

What error u are getting?


And add some more codes

Comment: ck answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980899/how-to-can-change-ui-in-other-threads/35982468#35982468

Answer (score 3):

The basic facility to run something on the JavaFX application thread is [Platform.runLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).  However, by your comments, you seem to also want to run the something on the JavaFX application thread after a delay, so that is what this answer addresses.

---

The code below will schedule to do something on the JavaFX application thread after a 5 second delay:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
    pause.setOnFinished(event -> doSomething());
    pause.play();
});
```

In your case, doSomething() is:

```
lblToast.setText(6+"");
```

This is similar to the solution to:

- [JavaFX 8: how to add a timedelay to a listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784037/javafx-8-how-to-add-a-timedelay-to-a-listener)

A (minor) advantage of the PauseTransition over the use of ScheduledExecutorService is that the transition does not require an additional thread.  A disadvantage is that the ScheduledExecutorService returns a ScheduledFuture which might give you a bit more control over the process as you can call methods like cancel() or isDone() on the ScheduledFuture (that extra control might not be important for your application though).

Comment: @saman1046 jewelsea is right about the advantage(s) of his solution. Furthermore I suspect you don't need the control provided by a `ScheduledFuture` like in my solution, so just stick with his solution (which is simplier). :-)

Answer (score 2):

[ScheduledExecutorService.schedule()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule-java.lang.Runnable-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) allows to execute a task after a specified delay.
[Platform.runLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) executes the `Runnable` on the JavaFX-Thread.

```
ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
Runnable setLabelOnUI = () -> Platform.runLater(() -> lblToast.setText(6+""));
ex.schedule(setLabelOnUI, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: After a specified time

Comment: @saman1046 I updated my answer to specify a delay before the execution.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: Make sure the label variable is static so the Runnable Thread can access it!
Heres the syntax:

```
Runnable displayRunnable = new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                        //Enter Code to Change UI here!

                        }
 };
//Display Runnable allows us to modify UI components
Display.getDefault().syncExec(displayRunnable);
```

Comment: If you're having a illegal thread exception, calling Display.getDefault().syncExec(Runnable r); is the way to go. I believe your question addressed inserting a timer. Just insert the timer code block inside of the function run.

Comment: what is Display class?