# Automatically generate EventHandler after a specific time without user input in TextField (JavaFX)

Tags: java, textfield, eventhandler

### Current Implementation:

currently the user need to press the **Enter key** to generate an EventHandler to make my app do something with the input string in the TextField.

```
 textFieldSearchProductNumber.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent keyEvent) -> {
            if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                if (textFieldSearchProductNumber.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    // ... database query: string content of textFieldSearchProductNumber
                } 
        });
```

### Target:

I would like to make the TextField generate an EventHandler as soon as the user stops the input (Maybe with help of a timer or any other recommendations)

- further input to textfield is observed
  -> timer is reset to 500ms and textfield waits again for input
- **no further** input to textfield with timer elapsed
  -> textfield pass its content to database search method

How would you go about in writing this sort of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this code snippet provided by [jewelsea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea), which works great for my simple application ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784037/javafx-8-how-to-add-a-timedelay-to-a-listener)).
He also mentioned about using ReactFX for a more sophisticated solution ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263008/wait-before-reacting-to-a-property-change-javafx-8))

```
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
textField.textProperty().addListener(
    (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        pause.setOnFinished(event -> doSomething(newValue));
        pause.playFromStart();
    }
);
```